# Mysql can't create user / grant privileges on existing ones (access denied)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-10.04

After installing Mysql through apt-get on Ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS and messing around with it I'm in the position where I have no account that can do any operation to grant privileges or create a new user.

I can only connect to it via

> mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf

```
select host,user ,select_priv, Create_user_priv from mysql.user;
```

returns the following table:

```
+-----------+------------------+-------------+------------------+
| host      | user             | select_priv | Create_user_priv |
+-----------+------------------+-------------+------------------+
| localhost | apsc             | N           | N                |
| localhost | pma_GSn1wBscFLp0 | N           | N                |
| localhost | pp_sb_db         | N           | N                |
| localhost | debian-sys-maint | Y           | Y                |
| localhost | admin            | N           | N                |
| localhost | pma_FoXErUK90AbF | N           | N                |
+-----------+------------------+-------------+------------------+
```

How can I create a root-user with all privileges? A full reset would be fine by me.

Commands like the following one only return `access denied` errors

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Comment: You can use  `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server` It will ask you to enter root password. Once you are done connect to it  using  `mysql -uroot -pyourpassword`

Comment: I tried sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5, entered the password twice but then it goes back to the CL and just hangs.

Comment: You could try to remove/purge and reinstall it over again. "just hangs" isn't sufficient info.

Comment: Have you just done a `sudo mysql -uroot`? With my experiences with Ubuntu, a mysql password is set on the distro install and not when you install/upgrade the package. They account for this by placing the root password in an encrypted file. Passing the mysql command without the `-p` option should let you in.

Comment: Yup ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Answer (score 3):

There appears to be no root user in your mysql database. The debian-sys-maint user is the root equivalent. Here is how to add a root user:

```
mysql -u debian-sys-maint -p
```

When prompted for a password, enter the one located in `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf` once inside the database, you should be able to run:

```
grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'yourpassword' with grant option
```

Comment: starting the mysql-console with debian-sys-maint worked but when I try  create user 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; it gives me this error ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'localhost'

Comment: The esiest way to connect to the database is with `sudo mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`.  Then you don't need to enter the password.  It is read from debian.cnf.  And in no way ever cange the contents of `debian.cnf` without changing the password for `debian-sys-maint` user too. That will make the package managing of `mysql-server` stop working.  Read `/usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.5/README.Debian.gz` for more information.